# How to query solr to get the complete result rather eliminating the empty values in the result

Tags: search, solr

I have application which has solr search facility. When i query for search result comes only fields which has the values. How to get the result with empty field values in solr? How to get all the fields in result even though the value of a field is empty?

Answer (score 0):

Only the fields present is stored with each document, so if you want to keep empty fields actually available, you'll have to explicitly index empty content into the field. How you do that depends on how you're indexing documents to Solr today.

You can work around this by fetching the schema for the core / collection you're querying first, retrieve the field names and adding empty fields for each field present in the schema, if necessary.

It'll probably be easier to assume that missing fields are empty, and wrap your code in a check to see if the field is present, and if not, return an empty value instead.

The reason for this is that while Solr uses a schema, the underlying Lucene library does not - any document can contain a set of field names unrelated to the other documents present in the index. Since the schema can change independent of the content of the index as well (a schema change will not update existing documents), returning non-existing fields isn't straight forward - and for most cases the document returned should be as close to possible to what was actually indexed.